# createPortal as child function not working

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to `createPortal` as a child. I tried rendering it as:

```
{ () => createPortal(<PrivacyContent />, document.getElementById('privacy')) }
```

and also as

```
{ createPortal(<PrivacyContent />, document.getElementById('privacy')) }
```

However neither of them load anything.

The only way to get it to load is by going into `<PrivacyContent>` component and having it return `createPortal` like this:

```
class PrivacyContent extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return createPortal(
            <React.Fragment>
                <button>Click me</button>
            </React.Fragment>,
            document.getElementById('privacy')
        )
    }

}
```

I was hoping to not do `createPortal` inside the contents, but instead do it at the parent level like this, any ideas why it's not working:

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import { createPortal, render } from 'react-dom';

const PrivacyContent = lazy(() => import('./pages/legal/PrivacyContent'))

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.testIfPathname('/legal/privacy') &&
                    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                        { () => createPortal(<PrivacyContent />, document.getElementById('privacy')) }
                    </Suspense>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }

    testIfPathname(pathname) {
        return window.location.pathname.toLowerCase() === pathname;
    }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

Comment: Your first example shouldn't work as this is not a valid child for `Suspense` , i tried you second example and it worked fine: `{ createPortal(<PrivacyContent />, document.getElementById('privacy')) }`

Comment: Thank you @Sagivb.g I'll keep trying maybe I simplified my question wrong. Can `<Suspense>` but the immeidate child of `createPortal`? ie: `createPortal(<Suspense><LazyComponent /></Suspense> ,...)`?

Comment: iv'e made an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/0q1zmo2wpn)

Comment: Thank you @Sagivb.g! I will keep you updated on my progress.

Comment: My gosh @Sagivb.g I have no idea whats going on. I recreated my example exactly - https://codesandbox.io/s/l5moryyxoz - it works in sandbox but not in my code. In my code the `render` of `PrivacyContent` triggers, however the render jsx is not printed into dom.

Comment: Oh wow, on my actual site, it seems its intermittent, sometimes it renders sometimes it doesn't. That is so weird. @Sagivb.g

Comment: Ah @Sagivb.g for me it is staying with the "fallback" rendered.

Comment: @Sagivb.g i posted my exact problem - https://stackoverflow.com/q/53896538/1828637

Comment: Gosh @Sagivb.g there was a vue component that was loading and freezing the innerHTML.